# server choice on phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I'm working on our database and I use for that a former project I did.
I used to work with a phpmyadmin version where I didn't need to specify the server choice.

Today I work on the version 4.1.14.8 and I have to specify the server number.
What I like to know is how can I specify that in my connection string by using doctrine.

Here's what I have for the moment :

```
<?php

// Doctrine (db)
$app['db.options'] = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'port'     => '3306',
    'dbname'   => 'dbname',
    'user'     => 'usr',
    'password' => 'pwd',
);
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot follow the question.

Comment: Ok...
We use nuxit to host our database : phpmyadmin.nuxit.com
We use the server number 50 and I have to specify that in my doctrine configuration.

For the password, for instance, I juste have to write: 

" 'password' => 'pwd',".

My question is what is the word I have to use to specify my server choice.

Hope it's clear

Comment: OK, so your question has nothing to do with phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

The array value:

```
'host'     => 'localhost',
```

Is what you use to specify the server to use. In the above it is set to 'localhost'. You could just enter in the IP address if your MySQL database is on another host.

Comment: I've found a code monkey solution.

Writing https://phpmyadmin.nuxit.com/tbl_structure.php?server=10, it automatically complete with the server number 50.

I will do with that but I'm sure there is a parameter to specify the server number.

Thanks again!